# getApplicationContext() cannot be cast Android

Tags: java, android, casting, singleton

I am creating an Application Singleton for sharing data among activities.

**AppData**  (Singleton)

```
import android.app.Application;

public class AppData extends Application {

    private String data;
    public String getData(){ return this.data;}
    public void setData(String data){this.data = data; }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class SectionListExampleActivity extends Activity {

    AppData appData;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_list_layout);

        appData = (AppData) getApplicationContext();  // error here

    }
```

Error:  `android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example....AppData`

Comment: do you set your AppData class as an application in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you forget to define the application in `Manifest.xml`?

You need something like:

```
 <application
    android:name="package.AppName"
    ...
 </application>
```

Comment: Cheers! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your application class in manifest and try it

```
public class SectionListExampleActivity extends Activity {

    AppData appData;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_list_layout);

        appData = (AppData) getApplication();

    }
}
```